# Making CSS Image Rollovers Appear (vs. Slide in)

Tags: css, rollover

Not sure what's going on but I suspect jquery is at work... I am using an image sprite on hover, but the image slides in from the right as opposed to appear in place. See the blue bubble turn into a red bubble at http://www.maidinhoboken.com/testpage/

How do I get it to appear in place?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="rollover" title=""><span class="displace">Test</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
a.rollover {
display: block;
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
text-decoration: none;
background: url(images/bubble_rollover1.png);
}

a.rollover:hover {
background-position: -190px 0;
}

.displace {
position: absolute;
left: -5000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS file on line 1666

```
a.rollover, a.rollover:hover {
    transition: none; 
    -moz-transition: none; 
    -webkit-transition: none; 
    -o-transition: none; 
    -ms-transition: none; 
}
```

You have a transition set somewhere in your style sheet that is being inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You have CSS transition which makes the image roll instead of appear. Put `transition:none` rule into a.rollover:

```
a.rollover {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url(images/bubble_rollover1.png);

  /* add this */
  transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: none; /* Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have transitions set on the links here

```
a, a:visited {
    color: #3FB6D7;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

remove it and it should be fine